# Magento 2: UI Component - Disable Fieldset with condition?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

I try it but not working. everyone can help me plz!
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using magento2.3.1 need to change your filed component code in xml file like below

```
           <field name="sort_order" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Sort Order</label>
                    <dataScope>sort_order</dataScope>
                     <imports>
                        <link name="disabled">${ $.provider}:data.do_we_hide_it</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </field>
```

Comment: your dataProvider code will remain same... just change your filed code like above

Comment: Do you know hidden fieldset ?

Comment: @NewBie means? what is your requirement?

Comment: I want hide tab in form ui components.

Comment: @NewBie Please add new question ... If not me other can help you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can override getMeta() function in your DataProvider class

```
public function getMeta()
    {
        $meta = parent::getMeta();
        $id = $this->request->getParam('entity_id');
        if(isset($id)){

            $meta['fieldset_name']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 1;
        }
        else{
            $meta['fieldset_name']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 0;

        }
        return $meta;
    }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class into the fieldset tab as below.

```
<fieldset name="testingproduct" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Custom\Form\CustomFieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
...
```

You need to add the fieldset condition in the specified class.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Custom\Form;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class CustomFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;

        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    //This method is responsible for show and hide the fieldset

    public function prepare()
    {
        $visiable = false; // do some work to get boolean value;
        $config = $this->getData('config');
        $config['visible'] = $visiable;
        $this->setData('config', $config);
        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

Thanks :)